# Multiple TextViews in single TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to achieve the below layout. [image]

So the number and text should be 2 different TextViews. When I place them in a RelativeLayout, I get the image below :
[image]

So basically second TextView does not start from the beginning once it is too long to fit on one line. How do I achieve that, then?

Here the code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="5900"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText"
        android:text="This is the text associated with the previous number. This is the required format."

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ahh,  you mean there is no way.  Custom view,  etc,  nothing.

Comment: Well, you definitely can create a custom view which will behave like that. Go give it a try.

Comment: Sorry,  I read your can as can't.  Will try.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Will update the question. I meant textview. This is not supposed to be user editable. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: In case of TextViews, yes, you can have different formatting and clickable links in the same TextView, by using `HTML.fromHtml()`

Comment: Yes, my bad. Changed from editText to textView.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. I was thinking of a more robust solution where I don't have to use HTML and I can create custom text view with number followed by text. I'll try both custom view and fromHtml() Solution.